# Controller and Templates files are not editing (not a cache problem)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, opencart

*Hello, this is my very first time posting on forums for help so don't judge too harsh.*

I want to add some data to checkout and thankyou page for marketing purposes (like order id, product id etc)
I did such thing before on the same site, but the theme was changed and everything I wrote in View and Controller was reseted so I wanted to do the same again, but now there are some problems.

For example, I tried to edit **checkout/cart.twig** file to add 'product id' for each product from the page. Last time I just added 'product_id' to the **$data** variable in Controller and used it in **cart.twig** and it worked fine, but now it's not changing anything. I disabled cacheing and activated debug mode, so it is not a cache problem.

When I try to edit theme files directly from admin panel with the theme editor the changes are updated on the site, but I still can't acces my 'product_id' stored in $data from Controller **cart.php**, it's just a blank value everytime. I tried to send a constant string from controller to see if data is even sent to View but it still was blank.

Also, I've experimented and observed that if I remove product.twig file or cart.twig file, the frontend isn't completely dissapearing, it just has a broken layout and some elements are missing.

What may be the problem I can't edit .twig files directly without using opencart admin panel

I have installed version of opencart V 3.0.3.2 with 2 installed themes the default one and UltraStore OCTemplates. They both seem to be activated. Maybe it's the problem, I don't have much experience working with opencart.

Comment: Have you refreshed modifications in admin?

Comment: I disabled cacheing from cpanel and removed cache, should I also refresh from admin page?

Comment: yes you must in admin page refresh modifications and also clear cache in admin blue gear icon on the right upper corner.